Loomis and Sternberg Chapter 2, problem 2.19: defining the degree of a polynomial on a vector space (over R)
Exercise 2.19 of chapter 2 of L&S is:

A polynomial on a vector space V is a real-valued function on V which can be
represented as a finite sum of finite products of linear functionals. Define the degree
of a polynomial; define a homogeneous polynomial of degree k. Show that the set of
homogeneous polynomials of degree k is a vector space ${X}_{k}$.

I want (expect) my definition of the degree to satisfy to conditions: It is independent of the representation of a polynomial, and independent of the choice of basis I (shall) make.
After choosing a basis $\{a_i\}$ for $V$, I defined the degree of a polynomial $p = \sum_{i=1}^n l_1^{k_{1, i}}l_2^{k_{2, i}} \cdots l_m^{k_{m, i}}$ (with $k_{j, i} \ge 0$, $\sum_j k_{j, i} \gt 0$ and $l_i \in V^*$) to be the total degree of the multivariate polynomial $p \circ \psi $, where $\psi:\mathbb{R}^d \to V$ is the basis isomorphism. This definition satisfies the first condition, but I don't know how to show that it satisfies the second.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!

$V$ is not assumed to be finite-dimensional. Better define more intrinsically the degree to be $\le n$ iff there are only products of $\le n$ linear functionals in the sum.
